# Prove $GL(m,\Bbb{C}) \subset GL_+(2m,\Bbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I was trying to prove that $$GL(m,\Bbb{C}) \subset GL_+(2m,\Bbb{R})$$

If we treat the complex matrix $W\in GL(m,\Bbb{C})$ as $$W=
\begin{bmatrix}
W_r & -W_i \\ W_i &W_r
\end{bmatrix}\in R ^{2m\times 2m}
$$

I have no idea how to prove this I try to use the inverse formula for the block matrix however $W_r$ needs not to be invertible therefore the formula below does not work:

$$ \det {\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}}=\det(A)\det \left(D-CA^{-1}B\right).$$

I try to do some fundamental transformation to convert the $2m \times 2m$ matrix into triangle matrix, but it seems not very clear how to find such transformation.I try to analysis the eigenvalue of the $2m\times 2m$ matrix is seems not very clear.There must be many different ways to prove this result, but no idea in my mind.

Comment: A direct consequence of this result is that the complex vector bundle when treated as real vector bundle is orientable

Comment: I have an idea that use the variational characterization of the eigenvalue which says $R(M,x)={x^{{*}}Mx \over x^{{*}}x}={\frac  {\sum _{{i=1}}^{n}\lambda _{i}y_{i}^{2}}{\sum _{{i=1}}^{n}y_{i}^{2}}}$ has minimal value the smallest eigenvalue. However this is not a symmetric or Hermitian matrix

Comment: It is possible to do complex row transformations to $W$ to see that invertibility of $W$ is equivalent to those of $(W_r + i W_i)$.

Comment: Yeah I come up with a method using heavy machinery by showing the $GL_+(n,\Bbb{R})$ is connected however the $GL(n,\Bbb{C})$ is connected also therefore it continuous inject into a single component @daw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, any complex matrix is triangulable, and thus it suffices to prove this for triangular matrix. Let $V=\mathbb{C}^m$ and view $V$ as a real vector space of dimension $2m$ with ordered basis $$\mathcal{B}=\{e_1,e_1',e_2,e_2',\dots,e_m,e_m'\}$$
where $e_{k}=[0,0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0]^t, e_k'=[0,\dots,0,i,0,\dots,0]^t$. Here $1$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}$ are in the $k$-th position. Let $$g=\begin{bmatrix}z_{11}&*&*&*\\ 0&z_{22}&*&*\\ 0&0&\dots &*\\ 0&0&\dots&z_{mm}\end{bmatrix}\in GL_m(\mathbb{C}),$$
which acts on $V$ in the natural way.
Write $z_{kk}=x_{kk}+iy_{kk}$ with $i=\sqrt{-1}, x_{kk}, y_{kk}\in \mathbb{R}.$ Let us consider what $ge_k$ and $ge_k'$ look like. First, it is easy to notice that
$$g e_k, ge_k'\in Span\{e_1,e_1',\dots, e_k, e_k'\}.$$
Thus $ge_k, ge_k'$ are upper triangular in a block form. More precisely,
$$ge_k=x_{kk}e_k+y_{kk}e_k'+\sum_{j<k }c_{kj}e_j+d_{kj}e_j',$$
and $$ge_k'=-y_{kk}e_k+x_{kk}e_k'+\sum_{j<k }c_{kj}e_j+d_{kj}e_j'.$$
Thus in the basis $\mathcal{B}$, as an element of $GL(V_{\mathbb{R}})$, $g$ has the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}A_1&*&*&*\\0&A_2&*&*\\ \dots&\dots &\dots&\dots \\ 0&0&\dots &A_m \end{bmatrix},$$
where $A_k$ has the form
$$A_k=\begin{bmatrix}x_{kk} &-y_{kk}\\ y_{kk} &x_{kk} \end{bmatrix}.$$
Note that $\det(A_k)=z_{kk}\overline{z_{kk}}$. Now the assertion is clear. Actually, it proves that $\det(g_{\mathbb{R}})=\mathrm{Norm}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(g)$. This is true for more general field extension. It is not necessarily to require it is $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me write $W = A+iB$ with real matrices $A,B$.
Then
$$
\pmatrix{I&iI\\0&I}\pmatrix{A &-B \\  B & A} \pmatrix{I&-iI\\0&I}
= \pmatrix{I&iI\\0&I}\pmatrix{A &-iA-B \\  B & A-iB}
=\pmatrix{A+iB & 0 \\ B & A-iB }.
$$
Hence $\pmatrix{A &-B \\  B & A}$ is invertible if and only if both $A\pm iB$ are invertible.

By assumption, $A+iB$ is invertible. Define the polynomial $p := \det(A+tB)$,
which has real coefficients. By assumptions, $p(i)\ne0$, so $p(-i)\ne0$. And $A-iB$ is invertible.

In addition, $\det\pmatrix{A &-B \\  B & A} = p(i)p(-i)$.
Since $i^4=1$, $p(\pm i)$ has the form
$$
p(\pm i) = \mp ai - b \pm c i +d
$$
with real coefficients $a,b,c,d$,
so that
$$
p(i)p(-i) = (- ai - b + c i +d)(+ ai - b - c i +d)=(b-d)^2 + (a-c)^2\ge0.
$$
This proves $\det\pmatrix{A &-B \\  B & A}>0$.