# behavior of determinant and trace of a matrix under restriction of scalers

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is inspired by this one [Prove $GL(m,\Bbb{C}) \subset GL_+(2m,\Bbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438939/prove-glm-bbbc-subset-gl-2m-bbbr/4439009#4439009)

Let $E/F$ be a finite field extension and let $V=E^m$. Of course $V$ can be viewed as a vector space over $F$. Write $V_F=\mathrm{Res}_{E/F}(V)$ for the vector space $V$ when it is viewed as an $F$-space. Given an $E$-linear operator $T: V\to V$, let $T_F: V_F\to V_F$ be the corresponding linear operator obtained by restriction of scalers. What is the relation between $\det(T)$ (resp. $\mathrm{Tr}(T)$) and $\det(T_F)$ (resp. $\mathrm{Tr}(T_F)$)? A natural guess is
$$\det(T_F)=\mathrm{Norm}_{E/F}(\det(T)), \quad \mathrm{Tr}(T_F)=\mathrm{Tr}_{E/F}(\mathrm{Tr}(T)). $$

Some cases are easy to prove (eg. when $E/F=\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$).

Are the above expectations correct for general field extensions? If yes, is there a quick proof of these facts? Any comments/references will be appreciated.

Comment: This question was asked here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309963/determinant-and-restriction-of-scalar, at least for the determinant part. But the possible solutions posted in the comments are not very satisfactory. One comment says that it follows from a proposition of Bourbaki's algebra III, 9.4, proposition 6, but I don't know why. Hopefully someone will provide/point out a more natural proof.

Comment: Okay, it is indeed proved in Bourbaki, Algebra, Chapter III, p.4, proposition 6, page 546 in Springer's English translation version. Anyway, since it might be useful for others, I will leave this question here.